# Default value in method

Tags: c#

I would like to have a method with default values.

Interface:

```
 public interface IMyFormatter
    {
        Bitmap Generate(string number, int width, int height);
    }
```

Concrete class:

```
 public class DefaultFormatter : IMyFormatter
    {

        private const int DEFAULT_BARCODE_WIDTH = 148;

        private const int DEFAULT_BARCODE_HEIGHT = 20;

        private const TYPE DEFAULT_BARCODE_TYPE = TYPE.CODE128;


        public Bitmap Generate(string Number, int Width = DEFAULT_BARCODE_WIDTH,
             int Height = DEFAULT_BARCODE_HEIGHT)
        {
            var zoneBarcode = new Barcode(Number, DEFAULT_BARCODE_TYPE);
            return new Bitmap(zoneBarcode.Encode(DEFAULT_BARCODE_TYPE, zoneBarcode.RawData, barcodeWidth, barcodeHeight));
        }
```

Usage:

```
var number = "1000";
var barcodeToPrint =_barcodeFormatter.Value.Generate(number);
```

I tried to modify interface like this (and adjust method in class to int? ):

```
public interface IMyFormatter
        {
            Bitmap Generate(string number, int? width = null, int? height = null);
        }
```

but values in my class are null, instead of default values and I get exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: Put the default values in the interface. To do this, you will probably need to extract the constants out to another class, which can be accessed both from `IMyFormatter` and from `DefaultFormatter` (since interfaces can't have constants defined on them):

```
public static class FormatterDimensions
{
    public const int DEFAULT_BARCODE_WIDTH = 148;
    public const int DEFAULT_BARCODE_HEIGHT = 20;
}

public interface IMyFormatter
{
    Bitmap Generate(
        string number,
        int width = FormatterDimensions.DEFAULT_BARCODE_WIDTH,
        int height = FormatterDimensions.DEFAULT_BARCODE_HEIGHT);
}
```

Note that you will *also* need the default values in the method, in order to support some other CLR languages such as IronPython:

```
public class DefaultFormatter : IMyFormatter
{
    public Bitmap Generate(
        string number,
        int width = FormatterDimensions.DEFAULT_BARCODE_WIDTH,
        int height = FormatterDimensions.DEFAULT_BARCODE_HEIGHT)
    {

    }
}
```

---

Option 2: use `int?` instead. You'll need to do this both on the interface and the implementation:

```
public interface IMyFormatter
{
    Bitmap Generate(string number, int? width = null, int? height = null);
}

public class DefaultFormatter : IMyFormatter
{
    private const int DEFAULT_BARCODE_WIDTH = 148;
    private const int DEFAULT_BARCODE_HEIGHT = 20;

    public Bitmap Generate(string number, int? width = null, int? height = null)
    {
        int actualWidth = width ?? DEFAULT_BARCODE_WIDTH;
        int actualHeight = height ?? DEFAULT_BARCODE_HEIGHT;

        // Use actualWidth and actualHeight in your code
    }
}
```

Comment: I went with the second option and it worked perfectly, thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in calling the method of your interface or calling the method of you class.

So just as an example:

```
public interface IMyFormatter
{
    object Generate(string number, int? width = null, int? height = null);
}

public class DefaultFormatter : IMyFormatter
{
    private const int DEFAULT_BARCODE_WIDTH = 148;
    private const int DEFAULT_BARCODE_HEIGHT = 20;
    private const string DEFAULT_BARCODE_TYPE = "TYPE.CODE128";

    public object Generate(string Number, int? Width = DEFAULT_BARCODE_WIDTH, int? Height = DEFAULT_BARCODE_HEIGHT)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Number);
        Console.WriteLine(Width);
        Console.WriteLine(Height);
        return new object();
    }
}
```

So when you now create a new object of your `DefaultFormatter` and call the `Generate()`

```
DefaultFormatter formatter = new DefaultFormatter();
formatter.Generate("100");

//Output: 100
//Output: 148
//Output: 20
```

but if you call it with the Interface type you will get the following Output:

```
((IMyFormatter) formatter).Generate("100");

 // Output: 100
 // Output: null
 // Output: null
```

You will get the same output when you create your class as the interface type.

```
IMyFormatter formatter= new DefaultFormatter();
formatter.Generate("100");

// Output: 100
// Output: null
// Output: null
```

Comment: (This is because optional parameter values are baked into the call site at compile-time)